# shouldOverrideUrlLoading method isn't called in case of SPA

Tags: android, webview

Building an android app with WebView, facing a problem.

I'd like to put a single page app which is built with `react.js` into WebView, and control it on chaging url before load the page via `shoudOverrideUrlLoading()` method. But `shoudOverrideUrlLoading()` is never called.

However, in case of non-single page app, it just works.

Is it a problem between WebView and SPA? I guessed it would be, but there were no references.

Comment: `WebView.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is actually called on link navigations, for example when the user clicks a link on the page to navigation to another. It won't be triggered on those JS requests initiated by popular JS frameworks like Angular, Vue, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is only called for **renderer initiated** navigations. That basically means:

- The user clicked a link
- JS on the page clicked a link or otherwise tried to navigate (e.g., `window.location.href`)
- HTTP redirect for some other navigation (some 3xx HTTP code)

The opposite of a renderer initiated navigation is a **browser initiated** navigation. This would include any `loadUrl()`/`loadData()`/etc. method--`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is not called for these.

A single page application wouldn't navigate, hence why the API is not called. You could instead investigate a solution with [`addJavascriptInterface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)), where user clicks would trigger method calls on the injected JavascriptInterface (instead of calling out to AJAX directly).